# Where is the source code of exim4-4.89-2+deb9u4?

Tags: debian, source, exim

I would like to know where to find the source code of exim4, with specific version and revision, 4.89-2+deb9u4.

I have executed `apt-get source` but got an error message:

> apt-get source exim4=4.89-2+deb9u4
>
> E: Can not find version '4.89-2+deb9u4' of package 'exim4'
>
> E: Unable to find a source package for exim4

For various other revisions of exim4, I was able to find the source code in this way.

I also found the [source repository](https://sources.debian.org/src/exim4/) but it only has the source code of exim4 version 4.89-2+deb9u3~bpo8+1 and 4.89-2+deb9u5, not for 4.89-2+deb9u4.

Does it mean the source code of 4.89-2+deb9u4 is no longer available? Or is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for that particular version is available [on snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/exim4/4.89-2%2Bdeb9u4/). If you install `devscripts` you can retrieve it by running

```
dget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20190605T153608Z/pool/updates/main/e/exim4/exim4_4.89-2%2Bdeb9u4.dsc
```

You can also use [the corresponding tag](https://salsa.debian.org/exim-team/exim4/tree/4.89-2+deb9u4) in the Debian package’s repository.